# Add scroll left and right on a span in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a emoticon palette which has the form like this :-

Categories div and then the emoticons div:-

```
<div class="emoticonbox" ng-if="showEmoticons">     

    <div class="categories_emo">
        <span ng-repeat='cat in EmoticonCategoryPositions | limitTo: (EmoticonCategoryPositions.length-1)'>
            <img ng-if="currentEmoticonCategory==$index" ng-src='{{emoticonDirPath}}tabs/emo_{{$index+1}}_tab_selected.png'      
            class="emoticon_tab" ng-click='setEmoticonCat($index)'/>
            <img ng-if="currentEmoticonCategory!=$index" ng-src='{{emoticonDirPath}}tabs/emo_{{$index+1}}_tab.png' 
            class="emoticon_tab" ng-click='setEmoticonCat($index)'/>
        </span>

        <div class="categories--control">
            <div class="rect rect--left" ng-click="moveleft()"></div>
            <div class="rect rect--right" ng-click="moveright()"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapEmoticons">
        <img ng-repeat='emoticon in emoticonList[currentEmoticonCategory]' src='{{emoticonDirPath}}{{emoticon}}' 
        ng-click='  addEmoticon(EmoticonCategoryPositions[currentEmoticonCategory]+$index);main.messageClickFocus()' class="emoticons"/>
    </div>

</div>
```

I want to add left and right arrow keys in the categories div so that I can browse categories by clicking the respective arrow.

I have added as you see above categories--control and with this javascript.

```
$scope.moveleft=function(){

    var widthOneItem = parseInt($(".sticker_tab").first().css("width"))+parseInt($(".sticker_tab").first().css("margin-left"))+parseInt($(".sticker_tab").first().css("margin-right"))+parseInt($(".sticker_tab").first().css("padding-left"))+parseInt($(".sticker_tab").first().css("padding-right"));
    console.log(widthOneItem);
    $(".categories_sti").animate({scrollLeft: "-="+widthOneItem});
    console.log("Moving Left");}

$scope.moveright=function(){

    var widthOneItem = parseInt($(".sticker_tab").first().css("width"))+parseInt($(".sticker_tab").first().css("margin-left"))+parseInt($(".sticker_tab").first().css("margin-right"))+parseInt($(".col-md-3").first().css("padding-left"))+parseInt($(".col-md-3").first().css("padding-right"));
    console.log(widthOneItem);
    $(".categories_sti").animate({scrollLeft: "+="+widthOneItem});
    console.log("Moving Right");}
```

Doesn't seem to work as required, no movement at all.

Comment: There are tons of carousel libraries out there for you to use, could you not just implement one of them instead?

Comment: direct give values to scrollLeft without using '-= '.. I dont thinks so that It will get calculated this way